# Comment flags are broken

Tags: bug, comment-flags

If I flag a comment now, it puts the dialog off the page:

> [image: before]

It is only fixed by performing one of these actions:

- Maximize window (if not already maximized)
- Restore window (if maximized)

> [image: after]

I am running Windows and Firefox; also I tried Firefox in safe mode. I would be
interested to see what testing was done on this beforehand - as this seems like
a pretty glaring error. Please and thank you.

---

Inspired by the answer, the following CSS worked for me. It makes me sad to have to fix
Stack Exchange CSS; I would figure this community over all others would get it
right. Oh well.

```
aside {
  transform: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I could never reproduce this in Firefox Nightly 63.0a1.

Comment: +1 for "I would be interested to see what testing was done on this beforehand - as this seems like a pretty glaring error. Please and thank you."

Comment: @StevenPenny I'm comfortable with you using whatever you want. However this question should be closed or tagged as status-declined as you're running an unsupported browser per https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: @RobertLongson I just ran into this on Firefox ESR 52.9.0, which is definitely a *current version* (and thus I would think supported) according to Mozilla. Admittedly though its official end of life is only ~2 weeks away, which I suppose makes this a rather unimportant issue at this point. It's still really annoying though.

Comment: I duplicate this on firefox ESR 52.9.0 (64-bit) on Mac. I think clicking on a blank area on the dialog caused it to reposition to the middle.

Comment: I also have ths issue with FF ESR 52.9.0 (32-bit) :(   Like @r_alex_hall. a click on the form background flips the form to the browser window centre, as does a window resize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a userstyle that fixes it appearing in the top left corner. This requires the [Stylus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/) add-on and only has been tested on Firefox 56. ([install](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/a-stone-arachnid/SO-Unannoyingify/master/comment-flag-dialog-bugfix.user.css)) ([source](https://github.com/a-stone-arachnid/SO-Unannoyingify/blob/master/comment-flag-dialog-bugfix.user.css))

Answer (score 7):

Able to reproduce this on FF 56:

[image: FF 56]

But .. I'm not certain that we can support something that is (as the vendor says) "critically out of date". We try to maintain graceful backwards compatibility as far back as we can reasonably go because we understand that not everyone has a choice when it comes to the browser work or school lets them use (this goes back to us continuing to test in IE6 long after everyone else essentially stopped caring, all those years ago), but it seems to *only* happen on versions that FF themselves patched and dropped support for.

You can apply the hack as suggested if it solves the immediate problem in the interim.

I'm not putting a status-tag on it, and I'm sorry that it took so long to get an official response, it's just one of those weird ones we'd *like* to support if we can, but figuring that out is going to take a unit of work large enough that it'll have to be scheduled, and it's hard to say if that can happen while the problem is still relevant.

Comment: Personally, I decline to upgrade because Firefox Quantum [breaks stuff I rely on](https://superuser.com/q/1351717/133195), so I'm using either Firefox ESR or Pale Moon. I don't know how many others do the same.

Comment: @gerrit So far, most of my extensions still work or work again by now, and I don't really miss the few that are broken. YMMV, of course.

Comment: @gerrit right, I agree. The "critically out of date" is quite hyperbolic, worded this way to get people like tim to say what he just said. the truth is more nuanced, 56 is less than a year old and 57 has plenty of its own problems http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1411795