# Report comment dialog mispositioned

Tags: bug, user-interface, comment-flags

[image: Dialog window positioned on the top left, ¾ invisible]

For me, the modal/dialog window is positioned semi outside the screen. When resizing the window or opening the developer tools, the issue fixes itself. When resizing it back or closing the developer tools, the issue often reoccurs, but not always.

I'm using Linux with Firefox 55 for a bunch of add-ons that can still not be implemented in more recent versions. Not sure if anything changed in CSS vertical/horizontal alignment since then; positioning an element should be pretty compatible so I figured I'd report it and see if others can reproduce.

Comment: Firefox 52 ESR is the last ESR version of Firefox, and the current and previous ESR versions are supported, so if the bug can be reproduced there then this can be fixed.

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog I looked into downgrading, but downgrading a profile is not supported so I can't do that either. I'm stuck at 55 for the time being.

Comment: Can't you use a different browser?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Resizing or opening dev tools works so it's not a huge stopper, but I assumed that (since css positioning isn't very different across browsers or versions) it was broken for more people than just me. It doesn't have to be fixed for just me, but it might be nice to fix it for everyone -- assuming others can reproduce it.

Comment: There's a workaround in this question from other users on older Firefoxes.  Something's amiss in the transform. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313444/235711